# Unable to login to local DHIS2: Getting a null value in the SessionId

Tags: authentication, error, dhis2

I have installed DHIS 2 version 2.33.0 on a local instance following steps mentioned [here](https://docs.dhis2.org/master/en/implementer/html/install_server_setup.html).  I have also restored the sample database dump. I am able to create new users, but couldn’t log in using username as ‘admin’, or a newly created user. The page gets reloaded on the click of the Sign In button.

The following warning message is displayed in the log:

> WARN 2019-11-26 20:07:42,969 Authentication event
>   InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent: admin; details:
>   org.hisp.dhis.security.spring2fa.TwoFactorWebAuthenticationDetails@b364:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null (LoggerListener.java
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-1]).
>
> *** Getting a null value in the SessionId

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but it might help others : you need to put

```
server.https = off
```

in your dhis.conf file.

As I am only testing DHIS, I did not look for a real way to make it work with

```
server.https = on
```